# C# Windows 10 How To Proxy Change?

Tags: c#, proxy, registry, dllimport

I need change Windows 10 Proxy.But my code doesn't work.if i make proxyactive ethernet going :(

Here is my code ;

```
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
    public const int INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39;
    public const int INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;
    static bool settingsReturn, refreshReturn;

   public static void proxyactive()
    {
        RegistryKey RegKey1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);

        RegKey1.SetValue("ProxyServer", Globals.MainWindow.txtProxy.Text);
        RegKey1.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);

       // These lines implement the Interface in the beginning of program 
        // They cause the OS to refresh the settings, causing IP to realy update
        settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

    }


 public static void proxydeactive()
    {
        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);

        RegKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", Globals.MainWindow.txtProxy.Text);
        RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);


        settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You don't state what error you're getting, and what input value you're trying to enter. Format your question and code nicely. Please show some effort you've done to expect people make effort answering your question. You didn't even let us try debugging your app properly.

Comment: Maybe try running your app with elevated permissions.